# selectedBackgroundView hiding UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've added a `UIView` on top of a `UIImageView` in order to create an overlay effect on that given image. However there seem to be a issue regarding this and the `selectedBackgroundView`. Cause when i select a cell it seem to hide/remove the UIVIew (Overlay), How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `allowSelection` to false.